# jQuery: How to make $(this) selector work?

Tags: jquery, css, html

How to make $(this) selector work?

jQuery

```
$('.parent').find(".child1").html($(this).parent().find('.info').html());
```

eg HTML

```
 <div class= "parent>
 <div class="child1"></div>
 <div class="child2"></div>
 <div class="child2"></div>
 <div class= "info"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Never use such constructions

Comment: @MarkZucchini Why don't you recommend that? I'm new to this stuff.

Comment: Despite JavaScript allows (and perfectly executes) the constructions like above one, they completely unreadable for humans. When another programmer (or yourself couple of months later) will encounter such construction he probaly "freeze" for a minute tries to understand what this line of code do. That's why the programmers use indents, comments and so on. These things helps make code easy to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass a function to your `html` method and return desired text which you want:

```
$('.parent').find(".child1").html(function () {
    return $(this).parent().find('.info').html();
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pLjzh734/).

---

From [official jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function):

> **`.html( function )`**: A function returning the HTML content to set. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old HTML value as arguments. jQuery empties the element before calling the function; use the oldhtml argument to reference the previous content. Within the function, **`this`** refers to the current element in the set.